# Why below printf causes segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why below `printf` causes segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d", *intp);
    return 0;
}
```

Check it on [onlinegdb.com](https://onlinegdb.com/Bk1NXOo1V)

Comment: So you're telling us your compiler did not produce a warning?

Comment: I was learning stuff online and trying out code in online compilers and got this. But even if its warning prone, why is this so?

Comment: Try `int intp[]`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are trying to initialize a pointer with a brace enclosed initializer list of `int`s, which is invalid.

```
int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

If you try to compile your code with proper warnings enabled, you'll see the compiler warning messages like

> ```
> source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
> source_file.c:9:18: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>      int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5};
>                   ^
> source_file.c:9:18: note: (near initialization for ‘intp’)
> source_file.c:9:20: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
>      int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5};
>                     ^
> source_file.c:9:20: note: (near initialization for ‘intp’)
> source_file.c:9:22: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
>      int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5};
>                       ^
> source_file.c:9:22: note: (near initialization for ‘intp’)
> source_file.c:9:24: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
>      int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5};
>                         ^
> source_file.c:9:24: note: (near initialization for ‘intp’)
> source_file.c:9:26: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
>      int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5};
> ```

This statement in your code is a constraint violation and does not mean anything meaningful. For a scalar, the initializer should be a single expression: as stated in `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. [...]

Thus, a brace enclosed list is not a suitable initializer for a scalar.

You can change the pointer to an array and have that initialized with the initializer statement, but not a pointer.

Then, later, when you try to dereference, you're essentially making an attempt to dereference an *invalid* memory, which invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Changing your code to something like

```
 int intp[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

would do the job.

Comment: Is that `int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5}` really invalid? Because removing `printf` [does not give any error](https://ideone.com/xUBmgB).

Comment: Yup trying to understand them. But then what is the end result of `int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5}`? Nothing? Does the compiler simply ignores the line because of warnings, or changes the address value of `intp` to something and if yes to what?

Comment: [..continued from last comment] Why the compiler gives warnings, not compile time error? Especially when this: `int *intp; ntp = {1,2,3,4,5};` gives error on 2nd line. What is purpose of allowing `int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5}` with warnings?

Comment: Because you _can_ make a pointer from an integer without a cast, and you _can_ have a scalar initializer with excess elements.  But _usually_ doing either of these indicates a mistake and warnings exist to check that the programmer didn't do it intentionally for some purpose that the compiler cannot determine.

Comment: @paddy there cannot be excess elements in a scalar initializer, in Standard C

Comment: @paddy I believe my first question remained unanswered:  **(1)** "But then what is the end result of `int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5}`? Nothing? Does the compiler simply ignores the line because of warnings, or changes the address value of intp to something and if yes to what?"

Comment: @paddy Also I didnt get what do you mean by "you can make a pointer from an integer without a cast". Any example? Also what do you mean by "you can have a scalar initializer with excess elements". This is undefined behavior: `char a[3] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};`.

Comment: @M.M can you answer [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699782/why-below-printf-causes-segmentation-fault/53699813?noredirect=1#comment94260856_53699813) and 2 above: **(2)** Why the compiler gives warnings, not compile time error? Especially when this: `int *intp; ntp = {1,2,3,4,5};` gives error on 2nd line. What is the purpose of allowing `int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5}` with warnings? Should I ask new question for these?

Comment: @anir an array is __not__ a scalar type.

Comment: Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types. Array and
structure types are collectively called aggregate types.

Comment: ohhh ok, but I still dont get if my questions were answered: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699782/why-below-printf-causes-segmentation-fault/53699813?noredirect=1#comment94260856_53699813) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699782/why-below-printf-causes-segmentation-fault/53699813?noredirect=1#comment94260919_53699813)

Comment: @anir (1) enable highest level of warnings and treat all warnings as errors - your code will not compile. (Yes, these are the compiler options and they are there for a reason - to be used) (2) Same.

Comment: Re “The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression”: This is funny because an *initializer* is about the only expression in C that cannot be an *expression* as defined in the grammar. Because of course `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` is an expression; it has the value `5` using the comma operator. Per the grammar, an *initializer* is actually an *assignment-expression*, which bypasses the comma operator.

Comment: @anir: After displaying the warnings, most compilers will, if they continue compiling, ignore the excess values and convert the first value from an integer to a pointer. Whether they actually do this or not is not specified by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Tried [this](https://ideone.com/6Rkzhz): `int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5}; printf("%u",intp);`. It prints `1` confirming what u said: "ignore excess values & convert first value from an integer to pointer." (which is somewhat surprisingly unobvious) & address location `1` is out of accessible segment, thats why its causing segmentation fault. So I feel there is nothing wrong in first line `int *intp = {1,2,3,4,5};` (though what it does [assigning `1` to `intp`] is definitely unobvious), its just that address location `1` is simply unaccessible causing segmenation fault. Right? @Sourav

Comment: [...continued from last comment] The warnings we get have nothing to do with segmentation fault. With `int *intp = 5; printf("%d",*intp);`, I still get both segmentation fault and "warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast". Though the warning has nothing to do with segmentation fault. Right?

Comment: @anir you'd have to inquire with the gcc developers about that. It doesn't make much sense to me.